# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined RxJS

Tags: json, angular, jasmine, rxjs

I want to trigger this catch block and confirm that `handleError()` runs:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtService {
    private actionUrl: string;
    private headers: Headers;


    constructor(private http: Http, private configurationService: ConfigurationService, private _utilsSvc: UtilitiesService) {}

    getToken() {
        if (this.configurationService.config) {
            return this.http.post(this.configurationService.config.jwtUrl, { "brand": "IAG" })
                .map(this._utilsSvc.parseJson)
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }   
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
        let errorStatus = error.status;
        return Observable.throw(errorStatus);
    }
}
```

utilsSvc class:

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilitiesService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    fetchFile(url) {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise();
    }

    parseJson(response: Response) {
        return response.json();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass it invalid json to cause an error to be caught:

```
it("Should handle error", () => {
    let resOp = new ResponseOptions({
        body: "invalid json"
    });
    mockHttpResponse = new Response(resOp);
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
        connection.mockRespond(mockHttpResponse);
    });
    spyOn(jwtService, 'handleError');
    jwtService.getToken().subscribe((res) => {
        expect(jwtService.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

How do cause the catch block to catch the error?

Here is my whole test file:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
import { inject, TestBed, ComponentFixture } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { Headers, HttpModule, BaseRequestOptions, XHRBackend, Response, Http, ResponseOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from "@angular/http/testing";
import { Component, DebugElement } from "@angular/core";
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

import { AuthenticationLibrary } from "../../app/services/authenticationLibrary.service";
import { ConfigurationService } from "../../app/services/configuration.service";
import { FrontEndLoggingService } from "../../app/services/frontEndLogging.service";
import { JwtService } from "../../app/services/jwt.service";
import { UtilitiesService } from "../../app/services/utilities.service";

describe("Authentication service", () => {

    let mockBackend;
    let jwtService;
    let configSvc;
    let http;
    let feLogSvc;
    let mockHttpResponse;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpModule],
            providers: [
                { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
                ConfigurationService,
                FrontEndLoggingService,
                JwtService,
                UtilitiesService
            ]
        });

        mockBackend = TestBed.get(XHRBackend);
        http = new Http(mockBackend, new BaseRequestOptions);
        feLogSvc = TestBed.get(FrontEndLoggingService);
        configSvc = TestBed.get(ConfigurationService);
        configSvc.config = {
            enableFrontEndDebugLogs: true,
            baseUrl: "www.someurl.com",
            providerEndpoint: "someMachine",
            categoriesEndpoint: "someCatEndpoint"
        }

        jwtService = new JwtService(
            TestBed.get(Http),
            configSvc,
            TestBed.get(UtilitiesService)
        )




    });

    it("Should get token", () => {        
        let resOp = new ResponseOptions({
            body: {
                "token": "Bearer ABC123",
                "brand": "AMI"
            }
        })
        mockHttpResponse = new Response(resOp)
        mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
            connection.mockRespond(mockHttpResponse);
        });
        jwtService.getToken().subscribe(response => {
            expect(response.token).toBe("Bearer ABC123");
        });
    });

    it("Should handle error", () => {
        let resOp = new ResponseOptions({
            body: "sdvhfujvn"
        });
        mockHttpResponse = new Response(resOp);
        mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
            connection.mockRespond(mockHttpResponse);
        });
        spyOn(jwtService, 'handleError');
        jwtService.getToken().subscribe((res) => {
            expect(jwtService.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show how do you construct jwtService

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here

```
spyOn(jwtService, 'handleError');
```

spyOn will override this method so it will not return anything while catch is expecting you to return an observable.

To fix this you need to return from that method

```
it("Should handle error", () => {
        let resOp = new ResponseOptions({
            body: "sdvhfujvn"
        });
        mockHttpResponse = new Response(resOp);
        mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
            connection.mockRespond(mockHttpResponse);
        });
        spyOn(jwtService, 'handleError').and.callFake(function () {
            return Observable.from("fake error");
        });
        jwtService.getToken()
            .subscribe((res) => {
                expect(jwtService.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
    });
```

This test will work but I am not sure if this test make any sense

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to not change the `getToken` method? That is the method I'm testing. Strictly speaking I shouldn't change it.

Comment: This method is invalid :) but yes its possible i asked you to post full configuration of your spec, i want to see how you construct service in your test, specially how do you provide private configurationService: ConfigurationService

Comment: Cheers, I have posted the whole spec file now.

Comment: I still get the same error. Note that the top test in my spec file does pass.